# Highlighting box within a matrix

Tags: align, matrices, highlighting

I'm trying to ilustrate how matrix multiplication works with the following code:

```
\begin{align*}
&  \begin{pmatrix}
     1 &2 \\
    -1 &0 
   \end{pmatrix} \\
   \begin{pmatrix}
    3 & 2 \\
    1 &-2 
\end{pmatrix} & \begin{pmatrix}
    ? & ? \\ ? & ?
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
```

With the following result:

[image]

I'd like to add some highlighting boxes like this:

[image]

I've seen some ways of doing boxes like these, but they don't seem to work properly within matrices (the & symbol for separating columns doesn't do its job when put within the boxes). Is there a way to do these that plays nicely with matrices? Also, is there a way to nicely align the top and bottom right matrices? Because right now they're aligned at the parenthesis, and it looks a bit odd.

Comment: Have a look (and a search here) at nicematrix: https://mirror.dogado.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/nicematrix/nicematrix.pdf .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to make the whole expression as one array using `nicematrix` and add the parentheses using `\SubMatrix`. The highlighting boxes can be drawn with `tikz` using the `fit` library.

Note that `\SubMatrix` doesn't add space for the parentheses, so some additional space needs to be added between columns 2 and 3.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{NiceArray}{cc@{\hspace{1.5em}}cc}
& & 1 & 2\\
& & -1 & 0\\[1ex]
3 & 2 & ? & ?\\
1 & -2 & ? & ?
\CodeAfter
    \SubMatrix({3-3}{4-4})
    \SubMatrix({1-3}{2-4})
    \SubMatrix({3-1}{4-2})
    \tikz{
        \node [draw, red, fit = (3-1)(3-2), inner sep=1pt]{};
        \node [draw, red, fit = (1-3)(2-3), inner sep=1pt]{};
        \node [draw, red, fit = (3-3), inner sep=1pt]{};
    }
\end{NiceArray}
\]

\end{document}
```